# How to reference class from another file as a param type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, jsdoc

I have a class that I want to reference as a jsdocs type in another file.

Something like this

```js
// src/models/MyClass.js
/**
 * @class
 * @alias module:MyClass
 */
class MyClass {
  foo() {

  }
}

// src/controllers/index.js
/**
 * @param {*} context
 * @param {module:MyClass} context.myClass
 */
const myFunction = (context) => {
  const bar = context.MyClass()
  bar.foo()
}
```

I want to reference the `myClass` as a type as a param on `myFunction` but it keeps coming back as type any so it's ignoring the jsdocs param type.

How can I properly reference `myClass` as a param type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the keyword `export` before the declaration of `class myClass`, so that you can import it in your other file.

By the way, I think that JSDoc is only a documentation tool, so your code is not affected by it.

Comment: I should have clarified that I am exporting my class at the bottom of my file but didn't include it in my example above. Also, VSCode will show you the type based on your JSDocs. It doesn't seem to be detecting the type of that class that is injected into the context param though

Comment: Alright then could you show us the content of your context param ? This would help resolving this issue.

Comment: `const context = { myClass: new MyClass() }`

Comment: It's weird that the myClass instanciation works, you're supposed to either do `myClass = new MyClass()` or `myClass: MyClass`. Since your context object has an any type itself (you dont declare the type anywhere so it's an implicit any), javascript doesn't know what's inside context and considers that everything inside is of any type. If you want to avoid that, you will have to create a new Context class that will have a MyClass property.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the way to do it. Just use [`@import`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types) to import a type from another file

```js
// src/controllers/index.js
/**
 * @param {object} context
 * @param {typeof import('../models/MyClass').MyClass} context.MyClass
 */
const myFunction = (context) => {
  const bar = new context.MyClass()
  bar.foo()
}
```

PS: I'm assuming `myFunction` is some kind of a factory function that accepts the class as a parameter like below. That's why there is also a `typeof` in from of the import so you can pass the class itself.

```
myFunction(MyClass);
```